# How to model Inter-dependent Worksheet in Java Array?

Tags: java, excel, algorithm, design-patterns, data-structures

I want to build two arrays, mimicking two worksheet in Excel.

In the spreadsheet world, let's called it Worksheet1 and Worksheet2.

The value of each cell in Worksheet2 is driven by formula specified in Worksheet2 consuming data from Worksheet1. In other words, if I change the data in Worksheet1, it will change the value in Worksheet2.

And also, some part of the cells in Worksheet2, also inter-dependent due to the formula in Worksheet2. For example, cell A2 in Worksheet2 depends on value from B2 in Worksheet2, and B2 value in Worksheet2 depends on value from B2 in Worksheet1.

In Java, I will have two two-dimensional arrays mimicking each spreadsheet.

Any idea on how best to implement this in Java?
1. Which is the best design pattern to do this so that the O(n) is acceptable?
2. Which is the best algorithm to simulate this structure? 
   The brute force way is I will always need to evaluate the value of each cells of Worksheet2 everytime the data in the cells in Worksheet1 changed. But this will be bad in performance.

Please advise! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually editing the values in worksheet1, create an update method to do it for you:

```
public void updateWorksheet(int x, int y, int val){ 

    worksheet1[x][y] = val;
    worksheet2[x][y] = doAlgorithm(val); 

}
```

This way, any time you edit worksheet1, worksheet2 will also be updated. You have to reevaluate the value of worksheet1 to get the value in worksheet2.

Another thing you could do is create a HashMap that stores every value you put in worksheet1 and its counterpart in worksheet2, so if you put in a value that was in worksheet1 already, you wouldn't need to use `doAlgorthim()` again if it is inefficient. For example:

```
//m is a HashMap<int,int>
public void updateWorksheet(int x, int y, int val){ 

    worksheet1[x][y] = val;
    if(m.containsKey(val))
        worksheet2[x][y] = m.get(val);
    else{
        worksheet2[x][y] = doAlgorithm(val);
        m.put(val,worksheet2[x][y]);
    }

}
```